# navigate form childwindow to usercontrol/parentwindow in silverlight mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

in my project i have one doubt..
 How to navigate from childwindow to parentwindow?
 i dont need to transfer data.
 Childwindow--> Button[Click]

if i click the button in the childwindow it will navigate me to a childwindow

Comment: Your question is not clear, why do you want to navigate to the child window when you click the button in child window?

Comment: Is Childwindow to Parentwindow navigation is possible or not in Silverlight mvvm..?

Comment: In my childwindow 2 buttons are there one for homepage.xaml and another one is Details.xaml. if i click the 1st button means it will goes to homepage.xaml.. this is my scenario..

Comment: You need to create a framework for that, you can't open a parent window from a child window.

Comment: thank you for ur valuable comment..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **complex application** where you most likely will need to transfer information between multiple Modules of your application and need to keep the loose coupled using **MVVM**, I would recommend checking out **Prism Framework**.

There is a complete course of Prism on http://www.pluralsight.com/ I recommend.

I would also suggest to download the prism on 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28950

Try it and see how to transfer information between different views and modules.